# Space padding in printf doesn't work

Tags: c, printf

I need to add variable space padding before my string. Here's the code:

```
unsigned int spaces = result % 16;
printf("spaces=%d\n", spaces); // spaces=12, for example.
printf("% *s\n", spaces, my_string);
```

It simply doesn't work - spaces are not added and I'm getting following warning in gcc:

`warning: ' ' flag used with ‘%s’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]`

How to fix that? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you. I just find out that this will work too `printf("%*s" "%s\n", spaces, " ", my_string);`

Comment: What you have is exactly the same as `("%*s%s\n", spaces, " ", my_string)`. Adjacent strings are silently combined.

Comment: note that there is also the option to pad a string with spaces up to a set total length, `printf("%*s", (int)spaces, my_string);` . Use `-` after `%` to left-justify (default is right-justify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
printf("% *s\n", spaces, my_string);
```

to this

```
printf("%*s%s\n", spaces, " ", my_string);
```

This should get rid of the warning and give the desired effect.

[EDIT]

I now saw that you found already the answer. What alexis says is also correct and will produce the same effect. Alexis's version is cleaner, I would say, so I am giving this as a solution, but the credits are on him.

You could also do something like this:

```
int width = 5;
printf ("%*d%*d\n", width, 10, width, 12);
```

which will print this:

`10   12`

[Source](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~cs150/reading/printf.htm)

So, if you think about it, you could this:

`printf("%*s\n", spaces, "foo");`

---

Why Alexis's version was synonym to your version in the comment?

Because  the compiler performs concatenation of two sequential strings (i.e. with a whitespace in between) to one.

This action is called *String literal concatenation*. Read more in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#String_literal_concatenation).